# Firestore security rules - `request.auth` is always null in react and next.js

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Firebase version: 9.15.0
React version: 18.2.0
Next.js version: 13.1.1
Jotai version: 1.12.1

I'm trying to make a request to my firestore database. I am logged in, and I can print my uid to console fine. In the FirebaseError error, it mentions my method `updateUserLicense`. I'm using Jotai for state management. It's interesting that the atoms are undefined when set in `onAuthStateChanged`. However, I don't use them in `updateUserLicense`, so it shouldn't be an issue.

I have a file that initializes firebase and it's respective services, and then those are exported and imported by the javascript files that contain functions such as `updateUserLicense`. This file is under the "services" folder:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB-ZPDz7RI6j07bxqfqcQqvuJC8CcQ5QFI",
    authDomain: "ai-docs-tool.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "ai-docs-tool",
    storageBucket: "ai-docs-tool.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "57784220238",
    appId: "1:57784220238:web:18bd4a9bc3843b5451611f",
    measurementId: "G-0L2LR8LHX1"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {auth, db};

export * from "./authentication.service";
export * from "./license.service";
```

Login button component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useAtom } from "jotai";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { loginWithGoogle, updateUserLicense, auth } from "../services";
import { userAtom, licensesAtom } from "../state";

export default function LoginButton() {
  const [user, setUser] = useAtom(userAtom);
  const [licenses, setLicenses] = useAtom(licensesAtom);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (newUser) => {
    if(newUser && user == null) {
      setUser(newUser);
      const license = await updateUserLicense(newUser);
      setLicenses(license);
    }
  });

  return (
    <button onClick={loginWithGoogle}>Login</button>
  )
}
```

Troublesome update function, in a separate file under a folder called "services":

```js
import {db} from "./index";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, setDoc, serverTimestamp, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { auth } from "./index";

export async function updateUserLicense(user) {
    if(user == null) return;
    console.log("UID:", user.uid); // Prints the uid passed in fine, so user is authenticated
    const docRef = doc(db, "license-keys", user.uid); // All of this code works when the security rules are read/write enabled for all.
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if(docSnap.exists()) {
        updateDoc(docRef, {lastRead: serverTimestamp()});
        return docSnap.data().licenses;
    }
    else {
        const newLicense = uuidv4();
        setDoc(docRef, {licenses: [newLicense], lastRead: serverTimestamp()});
        return newLicense;
    }

}
```

Security rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /license-keys/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My database, and the rules playground that shows it working if I pass in the uid by hand:
[image: Firestore]
[image: Firestore Playground]

I've tried using the rules playground, but it always passes with the uid that I use.
I tried printing the user.uid to see if it's there, and it is.
I've tried logging out, and then in and again, and it still doesn't work.
I tried downgrading to v8, but it just broke my project.